# GCC does not warn when using == op with a signed var and an unsigned literal

Tags: gcc, casting, compiler-warnings

Why does GCC warn only for situations 1 and 3 and not 2 in the code below ?

I'm compiling with -Wall and -g flags.

```
int main() {

    unsigned int ui = 4;
    int si = 6;

    if (si == ui ) { // Warning comparison b/w signed and unsigned
        printf("xxxx");
    }

    if (si == 2U ) { // No Warning --- WHY ???
        printf("xxxx");
    }

    if (si > 2U ) { // Warning comparison b/w signed and unsigned
        printf("xxxx");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html:

-Wconversion section:

> Do not warn for explicit casts like
>   `abs ((int) x)` and `ui = (unsigned)
>   -1`, or if the value is not changed by the conversion like in `abs (2.0)`.

Since `2U` is literal, gcc know that:

- if `si < 0`, then `(unsigned) si >= 2^31`, therefore `s1 != 2U`.
- if `si > 0`, then `(unsigned) si` has the same value as `si`, therefore `(unsigned) si == 2U` if and only if `si == 2`.

In conclusion, comparing the signed `si` with literal `2U` is the same as comparing `si` with `2`, i.e., the result of `si == 2U` would not be changed by converting `si` to `unsigned`.

If you compare with 2^32-1 (4294967295U), the largest in 32-bit unsigned int, which is not representable in `int`, then `si` could be equal to it even if `si` itself is negative, this may not be what you wanted, so a warning is generated with `-Wextra` option.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because there's no ambiguity in an equality comparison with constant in the range where signed and unsigned versions of the type overlap.

If I change it to

`if (si == 2147483648U ) {
        printf("xxxx");
    }`

I get a warning

(Actually, I had to add -Wextra before I got the warnings you reported)

Answer (score 0):

Chris thanks for your answer. I think it leads to the cause. My original thought was that the U suffix would cause this literal to be promoted to an unsigned type however I think that it is only promoted to an unsigned type when the number is greater than INT_MAX_32 that is > 2147483647.

Comment: It is indeed `promoted' to unsigned, but there is no difference when its value is less than 2^31 - 1.

Comment: @ryanli : if it is always promoted to unsigned then si == 2U should throw a warning as well. Why is 2147483647 the magical point where, with only the -Wall flag, should gcc start throwing a warning.I guess I do not understand your initial answer.

Comment: because `2U` is a literal, and although `si` is `signed`, gcc knows clearly at compile time that `si` can be compared with the value of `2U` without losing accuracy: if `si` is negative itself, it is not equal to `2U` after promoted to unsigned. But for literal values larger than 2^31-1, gcc throws a warning since `si` could be equal to the literal if `si` is negative, which may not be the result what you expected. And `-Wall` doesn't warn anything as the link in my answer shows.